# mapping for // behaves weird for regular search with paste

Tags: vim

I have a mapping to use // as a global git search in the project for word under the cursor:

```
nmap // :let @/="...
```

The problem is that after I added this mapping regular search behaves weird when I try to paste the search term. i.e. if I hit / and then Paste (Apple-v on Mac) I get the following instead:

```
/<t_<fa>X>
```

**Update.**

It really doesn't matter what is the exact mapping. for example, just try the following:

```
map // echo "test"<cr>
```

now type // and you will see `test` in the statusbar.

now type / and immediately hit paste. I get

```
/<t_<fa>X>
```

Comment: maybe it would help if you post your exact mapping command

Comment: try map // echo "test"<cr> ;)

Comment: I have the same behavior, that's funny. However when I launch MacVim in a terminal (without GUI) things are working fine. It seems to be a MacVim bug then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same behavior to. It seems to be a bug in MacVim as this doesn't occur in MacVim in terminal mode. 
The mapping (which key and what) doesn't seems to change anything. It seems that every time your press  while Vim is waiting for a key to complete a mapping, rather cancelling the mapping and doing what  should do, it cancel it but send this key.
The problem doesn't occur if you wait until mapping timeout.

You can reproducet it in insert mode like this

```
:imap vv vv
```

the type v and  fast enough in insert mode and you'll have the same X>.